# KQL search return System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, kql

I'm using kql to search files in a sharepoint online using CSOM in a sharepoint add-in. It works so far until 29th january 2021
I noticed that using the method new sharepointonlinecredential, passing username and password works.
I get the context using the tokenhelper class with GetClientContextWithAccessToken (suggested method for authenticate sharepoint add-in).
Could you help me?

Comment: Did you check to see if your token is still valid for what you're trying to access? Is it possible your token expired?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add the `QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal` permissions for search add-ins:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/search-add-ins-in-sharepoint#search-add-in-permissions